# How to efficiently get a value from the last row in bulk on SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, aggregate-functions

I have a table like so

```
Id | Type  | Value
--------------------
 0 | Big   | 2
 1 | Big   | 3
 2 | Small | 3
 3 | Small | 3
```

I would like to get a table like this

```
Type  | Last Value
--------------------
Small | 3
Big   | 3
```

How can I do this. I understand there is an SQL Server method called **LAST_VALUE(...) OVER .(..)** but I can't get this to work with `GROUP BY`.

I've also tried using `SELECT MAX(ID)` & `SELECT TOP 1..` but this seems a bit inefficient since there would be a subquery for each value. The queries take too long when the table has a few million rows in it.

Is there a way to quickly get the last value for these, perhaps using `LAST_VALUE`?

Comment: This is the canonical question for this problem: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/86415/retrieving-n-rows-per-group

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most efficient method might be `not exists`, which uses an anti-join for the underlying operator:

```
select type, value
from likeso l
where not exists (select 1 from likeso l2 where l2.type = l.type and l2.id > l.id)
```

For performance, you want an index on `likeso(type, id)`.

Comment: This is incredibly ingenious!

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using rownumber:

```
select
  type,
  value
from
(
  select 
    type,
    value,
    rownumber() over (partition by type order by id desc) as RN
) TMP
where RN = 1
```

Can't test this now since SQL Fiddle doesn't seem to work, but hopefully that's ok.

Answer (score 0):

I really wonder if there is more efficent solution but, I use following query on such needs;

```
Select  Id, Type, Value
From    (   Select *, Max (Id) Over (Partition By Type) As LastId
            From #Table) T
Where   Id = LastId
```